# Possible Javascript submit one value from multiple equal name input?

Tags: javascript

This code has two links with same name but different values. If i click first link, i want to get value 10.  Is it possible using javascript with link submit()??

```
    <form name="listpages" action="page.php" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="pgnum" value="10">
    <a href="javascript: document.listpages.submit()"></a> 
    <input type="hidden" name="pgnum" value="20">
    <a href="javascript: document.listpages.submit()"></a>  

    </form>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But you can use this code to achieve the desired results.:

```
<form name="listpages" action="page.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="pgnum" value="10">
  <input type="submit" name="pgnum" value="20">
</form>
```

### EDIT

The JavaScript way. I don't see why you want to stick to JS. Your code will be broken when a user has disabled JavaScript (by using NoScript, for example);

```
<form name="listpages" action="page.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="pgnum1" value="10">
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('pgnum1').name='pgnum';document.listpages.submit()">Option 1</a> 
    <input type="hidden" id="pgnum2" value="20">
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('pgnum2').name='pgnum';document.listpages.submit()">Option 2</a>  
</form>
```

Comment: Updated answer. The structure is preserved as much as possible. Why do you not want to use my first suggestion? The JavaScript-based implementations will break your code in many browsers.

Comment: Thanks for quick response .. i m just curious about javascript .. and wanted to hide '&page=1' on url.  You are right about javascript unable on some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a single hidden input and set it's value via the hyperlink:

```
<form name="listpages" action="page.php" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="pgnum" value="10">
<a href="#" onclick="document.listpages.pgnum.value = 10; document.listpages.submit(); ">10</a>
<a href="#" onclick="document.listpages.pgnum.value = 20; document.listpages.submit(); ">20</a>  

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single form and combine it with some javascript code to submit the form with the appropriate page number:

```
<form name="listpages" action="page.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="pgnum" value="1">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitPageForm(pageNo) {
        var form = document.forms.namedItem("listpages");
        form.elements.namedItem("pgnum").value = pageNo;
        form.submit();
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript: submitPageForm(20);"></a>
<a href="javascript: submitPageForm(30);"></a>
...
```

But be reminded that for websites it is actually recommended to use **GET** parameters to switch pages, content items etc.

Here is a very good guide on choosing between **GET** and **POST**: http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html

Finally, if you decide to switch to GET, you no more need the form at all. I.e. you can simply write:

```
<a href="page.php?pgnum=20"></a>
<a href="page.php?pgnum=30"></a>
...
```

Comment: thanks .. i will take a look at it.  Yeah .. i m doing pages index.  I want to try if it is possible to use javascript rather than get/post.

Comment: Yeah, my first proposal uses javascript and hides the page numbers.

The second proposal is much simpler and has the advantage of making all of your pages addressable. That's why I included it.